# Problems with sending json data to server from javascript using the POST method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to see the json data I sent to the server using XMLHttpRequest but it seems that the server is not receiving it, when I run the javascript the alert window will pop up but doesn't print anything. Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

On the client side, Java script

```
var obj = {"action": "nothing"};

var jsonString = "jsonString=" + JSON.stringify(obj);


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://myserver/main.php",true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",jsonString.length);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{           
      if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
}
xmlhttp.send(jsonString);
```

On the server,php

```
if(isset($_POST['jsonString'])) 
echo $_POST['jsonString'];
```

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means that you have to urlencode the string: `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))`. You also should send a Content-Length: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", jsonString.length);`. And check the `xmlhttp.status === 200` in `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @Saxoier                                                            Thank you I just edited my code according to your instructions but unfortunately it's still not working

Comment: Your first version has already worked. Maybe you redirect with apache's mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`, ...) or mod_alias (`Redirect`, ...). Then you possibly make an additional GET-Request and loose all your POST-Data. Have a look at Firebug->Network. There shouldn't be a 3xx HTTP status code for this request.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending JSON data, but the content-type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You should either send form/encoded data (`var obj="action=nothing"`) or set the content-type to JSON (`application/json`)

Comment: Thank you I just changed it to application/json but it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

James' solution works just fine, but if you are looking to send data using the application/json content type then you have to access the data in a different way.

For what you have server side,

```
if(isset($_POST['jsonString'])) 
echo $_POST['jsonString'];
```

change this (like James did):

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
```

to

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO USE THE application/json content type then you must change how you access it server side with:

```
    $json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_object = json_decode($json_string); 
    echo $json_object->action;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='json.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var obj = {"action": "nothing"};
var jsonString = "jsonString=" + JSON.stringify(obj);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","whereIPutThePHP.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",jsonString.length);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{           
      if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && (xmlhttp.status === 200)){
          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } 
}
xmlhttp.send(jsonString);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```